# Gerrit Setup using Docker image

Tags: docker, gerrit

I have installed gerrit using docker images.
I can run this gerrit setup with the below command:

```
docker run -ti -p 8080:8080 -p 29418:29418 gerritcodereview/gerrit
```

It keeps running.
I can access it with `localhost:8080`

Say, I create 3 users user1, user2, user3.

If by chance the running docker process is killed or exited and I run that command again, the setup comes up newly. All the old data or users are lost.

Even if the system goes down or rebooted, data shouldn't be lost or the users can't be deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to start the container with volume mount:

```
   -v /path/localhost/:/var/gerrit/git
   -v /path2/localhost/:/var/gerrit/db
   -v /path3/localhost/:/var/gerrit/index
   -v /path4/localhost/:/var/gerrit/cache
```

you can see in the [docs](https://hub.docker.com/r/gerritcodereview/gerrit) following example:

```
version: '3'

services:
  gerrit:
    image: gerritcodereview/gerrit
    volumes:
       - git-volume:/var/gerrit/git
       - db-volume:/var/gerrit/db
       - index-volume:/var/gerrit/index
       - cache-volume:/var/gerrit/cache
    ports:
       - "29418:29418"
       - "8080:8080"

volumes:
  git-volume:
  db-volume:
  index-volume:
  cache-volume:
```

it is up to you to use `named` or `mount` `volumes`

Comment: Should the `docker-compose.yaml` file be created?
Or is it already present when we install or run docker

Comment: no you need to create the file and make sure that you have docker-compose installed

Comment: otherwise you can run docker with the `-v` options like in the first example

Comment: Yes, docker-compose is installed
`
gerrit@roy:~$ docker-compose -v
docker-compose version 1.17.1, build unknown
gerrit@roy:~$ docker-compose up
ERROR: 
        Can't find a suitable configuration file in this directory or any
        parent. Are you in the right directory?

        Supported filenames: docker-compose.yml, docker-compose.yaml
        
gerrit@roy:~$
`

Comment: please refer to https://takacsmark.com/docker-compose-tutorial-beginners-by-example-basics/